# Focus window by title in GNOME Shell 41+ under Wayland

Tags: gnome, window-manager, gnome-shell

In my shellrc I have [a function](https://github.com/lucaswerkmeister/home/blob/7a4d0bdf1dc76a0397d5f456a8afb9f5862f7dfe/.bashrc.d/activate-window#L14-L35) to activate (focus / bring to the foreground) a window by its title, using the `org.gnome.Shell Eval` dbus interface. (The xdotool approach doesn’t work under Wayland.) This worked great until GNOME 41 [restricted the ability to call Eval](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/commit/7298ee23e91b756c7009b4d7687dfd8673856f8b). Does anyone have an alternative solution, other than enabling the new “unsafe mode” (which reenables Eval, but is apparently, well, unsafe) or writing a dedicated extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I couldn’t find any existing way of doing this, I eventually wrote my own GNOME Shell extension, [Activate Window By Title](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5021/activate-window-by-title/) ([source](https://github.com/lucaswerkmeister/activate-window-by-title)). It exposes a custom D-Bus interface that can be used instead of `org.gnome.Shell.Eval`, for example:

```
busctl --user call \
    org.gnome.Shell \
    /de/lucaswerkmeister/ActivateWindowByTitle \
    de.lucaswerkmeister.ActivateWindowByTitle \
    activateBySubstring \
    s 'Firefox'
```

Answer (score 3):

I found

https://github.com/CZ-NIC/run-or-raise

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1336/run-or-raise/

and this works perfectly.